# Visual Studio Code C++ include local Files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Since a few days I m trying to include my custom header-file

HelloWorld.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyFunctions.h"

int main(){
    printHelloWorld();
    return 0;
}
```

MyFunctions.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyFunctions.h"


int printHelloWorld(){
    std::cout <<"Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

MyFunctions.h

```
#pragma once
int printHelloWorld();
```

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVa7t.png)

Error Msg:

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\juriw\Desktop\Projekts\C++\Learning\" && g++ HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld && "c:\Users\juriw\Desktop\Projekts\C++\Learning\"HelloWorld
C:\Users\juriw\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCJZTCT.o:HelloWorld.cpp:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `printHelloWorld()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is there anything wrong so far?

I reinstalled multiple times vsc, the extensions and the compiler. I m new to this and dont know if the code is wrong or i messed up the configurations. Is there anything else I can show u, to identify the problem?

Comment: You need to compile and *link* both cpp files (not an issue with Visual Studio Code, but a problem with configuring your project)

Comment: Use a build tool: Make, CMake, Bazel, MSBuild